# API call request limit

Tags: api, get, request, key, limit

I have been looking into various different APIs which can provide my the weather data I need in JSON format. A lot of these API's have certain limits such as: in order to get more requests per minute, you need to pay more money per month so that your app can make more API requests.

However, a lot of these API's also have free account which five you limited access to them.

So what I was thinking is, wouldn't it be possible for a developer to just make lots of different developer accounts with an API provider and then just make lots of different API keys?

That way, they wouldn't have to pay anything as they could stick with the free accounts. Whenever one of the API keys has reached the maximum daily request calls, the developer could just put a `switch` statement in their code which gets their software to use a different API key.

I see no reason why this wouldn't work from a technical point of view... but, is such a thing allowed?

Thanks, Dan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would technically be possible, and it happens.

It is also probably against the service's terms, a good reason for the service to ban all your sock puppet accounts, and perhaps even illegal.

If the service that offers the API has spent time and money implementing a per-developer limit for their API, they have almost certainly enforced that in their terms of service, and you would be wise to respect those.

[(relevant xkcd)](https://xkcd.com/1494/)

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I will just stick to one API key and upgrade my developer account when necessary. Thanks :)